# Can't seem to resize table

Tags: tables, resize

I'm trying to resize a table because it doesn't fit and after doing some research, I found the `\resizebox{}` or `\scalebox{}` but they both don't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me with this?

This is my table:

```
\documentclass{bachproef-tin}

\usepackage{hogent-thesis-titlepage} % Titelpagina conform aan HOGENT huisstijl
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../Assets/}}
\usepackage{url}

...

\begin{document}

...

\section{Vergelijking}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        & UiPath & Automation Anywhere & WorkFusion & IntelliBot & Microsoft Flow \\
        \hline
        \hline
        Cursus op het platform & ja & ja & ja & ja & nee \\
        \hline
        Custom Activities & community & enterprise & community & community & ? \\
        \hline
        Example Row &  &  &  &  & \\
        \hline
        \hline
        Score & /60 & /60 & /60 & /60 & /60  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Vergelijking van de verschillende RPA Providers.}
    \label{Vergelijking}
\end{table}

...

\end{document}
```

I've noticed that the usage of makecell makes my table jump to a new page, can I prevent this?

[image: Table without the make cell]

[image: Table with makecell]

Comment: Do not resize tables to make them fit into the textwidth. This will give you inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: Please make our code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Do you use `geometry`? If so, please include the corresponding settings as well.

Comment: Instead of resizing the table, you can use `tabularx`, shorten the table headers/add linebreaks, manually decrease the font size, adapt the value of tabcolsep....

Comment: Thanks for the update. `bachproef-tin.cls` and `hogent-thesis-titlepage.sty` are unfortunately not standard classes/packages. Where did you get them from?

Comment: @leandriis They're from my school, I'm writing my thesis and I have to use these files

Comment: Are thouse files publically available somewhere? Without them, others can not compile your document

Comment: @leandriis I'm afraid they're not publicly available

Comment: In that case, It is quite hard to give you a specific advice on how you can make your table fit into the textwidth. I'd start by adding the `makecell` package ans introduce linebreaks in the very wide column headers as follows: `\makecell{Automation\\ Anywhere}`. If the result is still too wide, add the `tabularx` package to your preamble and see if `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X||c|c|c|c|c|}` (and of course `\end{tabularx}`) give you the desired result.

Comment: (Personally, I would also recommend to not use vertical lines and switch to the horizontal lines from `booktabs` for a more open and less caged look of the table)

Comment: @leandriis I'll check them all out, thanks a lot for trying without the correct files!

Comment: @MoutPessemier could you include a snapshot of the compiled table in your question